# Eager Load Nested Associations with Conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I think this is a lot simpler than the title probably lets on.  Here are my three models with the associations:

**Update**: associations were incorrect previously. Here are the corrected associations:

```
#app/models/call_service.category.rb
class CallServiceCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :call_services
end

#app/models/call_service.rb
class CallService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :call_service_category
  has_many :calls
end

#app/models/call.rb
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :call_service
end
```

So I have a group of call_ids for the calls I want:

```
@call_ids = [1,2,3,4]
```

**Initial step which works**:
What I want to do is grab only the `calls` with the ids specified in `@call_ids`.  Then, I want to eager load only the associated `call_services` for those grabbed `calls`.  The following does this perfectly:

```
@call_ids = [1,2,3,4]
@calls_by_service = CallService.includes(:calls).where("calls.id IN (?)", @call_ids).references(:calls)
```

This is great.  Now I can iterate through only those selected calls' `call_services`, and I can even list all of those selected calls per service like so:

```
<% @calls_by_service.each do |call_service| %>
  <p> <%= call_service.description %> </p>
  <% call_service.calls.each do |call| %>
    <%= call.name %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What is great about this too is that `@calls_by_service` does not contain ALL of the `call_services`, but instead only those `call_service` records associated with the `calls` specified in `@call_ids`.  Exactly what I want at this level.

**One Level Deeper which is where I am having trouble:**
This is great but I need to go one level deeper:  I want to display only the associated `call_service_categories` for the associated `call_services` of those selected `calls` specified by `@call_ids`.

In other words: I want to grab only the `calls` with the ids specified in `@call_ids`.  Then: I want to eager load only the associated `call_services` for those grabbed `calls`.  Then: I want to eager load only the associated `call_service_categories` for those grabbed `calls`.

A visual of the structure is like this:

[image: example]

So I want to be able to iterate through those associated `call_service_categories` (ex: 'Emergency Relief', 'Employment'), and then iterate through the associated `call_services` of those `calls` specified in the `@call_ids`, and then display those calls per service.

I figured out one level (by call_service), now I just need to figure out one level deeper (by call_service_category).

In the rails guides, I attempted looking at the section on [specifying conditions on eager loaded associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations).  I was not having success, but I think the answer is in that section.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like this:  `CallServiceCategory.includes(call_services: :calls).where(calls: { id: @call_ids }).references(:call_services, :calls)`?

Comment: Any by the way, how are you calling `calls` without `has_many` relation?

Comment: @potashin typo on my part.  I'll correct the relationships, and I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: One of `belongs_to` associations (in `CallService` or `Call`) should be actually a `has_one` (one-to-one relationship – `belongs_to` on the one side and `has_one` on the other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the `belongs_to` associations (in `CallService` or `Call`) should be actually a `has_one` (one-to-one relationship – `belongs_to` on the one side and `has_one` on the other). Apart from that, you can try the following code to produce a chained query with `left join`s and retrieve fields from all 3 tables:

```
CallServiceCategory.includes(call_services: :calls)
                   .where(calls: {id: @call_ids})
                   .references(:call_services, :calls)
```

I've noticed that you have a `through` association on your `CallServiceCategory` model, but as there would be no `:call_services` in `includes`, you can't reference fields from `CallService` model in `references` (you can, but they just won't appear in the actual sql query).

Comment: Well, looks like my edit was rejected so you will have to make the edit yourself.  There should simply be an `s` on `:call` located in your answer: `CallServiceCategory.includes(call_services: :calls)`.  Once that is updated I will accept your answer.  Thanks!